# Spring data JPA Postgresql Timestamp is null

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa, timestamp, spring-data-jpa

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.3 and spring-data-jpa 1.8.0. I created a table with a created_at column (type - timestamp without time zone):

```
CREATE TABLE users
(
  id bigint NOT NULL,
  created_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  updated_at timestamp without time zone NOT NULL DEFAULT now(),
  CONSTRAINT users_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
```

So if i try to get data using my entity class from this table the createdAt field is always null. My code:

```
@Column(name = "created_at", nullable = false)
@Type(type = "date")
@Temporal(value = TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
@CreationTimestamp
public Date getCreatedAt() {
    return createdAt;
}

@PrePersist
public void onPrePersist() {
    this.setCreatedAt(new Date());
}
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: How do you get data from the database?

Comment: I have a repository:
@Repository
public interface UserEntityRepository extends PagingAndSortingRepository<UserEntity, Long> {}      
So i do userEntityRepository.findOne(id)